# Django Elasticsearch dsl drf OR query

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-rest-framework, elasticsearch-dsl

How to make OR query (using django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf) with multiple contains statements?
Query in words: Search for objects where title contains "hello" OR description contains "world"

I can't find about it in documentation: https://django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.12/advanced_usage_examples.html#usage-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you need is [boolean query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) with should clause, its very easy to construct in JSON format, and validate the search results.

For Django, although I am not familiar, this page of [queries DSL](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#queries) and specifically [this sub-section](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search_dsl.html#query-combination) should fix your issue.